# Selecting Unicode U+hex notation from database

Tags: php, mysql, select, unicode

I have a table containing some data,

```
SELECT code, id FROM code WHERE id = 92;
+--------+----+
| id   | code|
+--------+----+
| كتب عربية | 92 |
+--------+----+
1 row in set
```

I need to be able to get this value from the SELECT-query,

```
U+0643 U+062A U+0628 U+0639 U+0631 U+0628 U+064A U+0629
```

Can MySQL do that? if not, what is the fastest and easiest way to implement such a thing?

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: Probably not easy to do in a simple query, because you’ll need to split the string into single characters first, and go over them in a kind of loop – a procedure might be better suited. What other ways there might be to implement this “fast and easy” depends on what you actually need this for, resp. in what environment … does it have to be done in MySQL, can it not perhaps be done in the processing step that comes after that (PHP script, …)? For example with a simple `json_encode` in PHP you’d be almost there already.

Comment: json_encode does the job. Thank you very much. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, for example with a simple `json_encode` in PHP could get you almost there already.

```
json_encode('كتب عربية');
```

will give you `"\u0643\u062a\u0628 \u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629"`.

If you need the exact `U+` format you specified in your post, you can get that with a `str_replace` on the json result, and a little `trim` on top to remove the `"` and an additional space:

```
trim(str_replace('\u', ' U+', json_encode('كتب عربية')), '" ');
```

will result in `U+0643 U+062a U+0628  U+0639 U+0631 U+0628 U+064a U+0629`.

(Careful though if you have “normal” characters in there, say something from the Latin alphabet – `json_encode` will not replace those with `\u` notation, but leave them as they are.)